# Forwarding mouse events to underlying flash

Tags: css, flash, pointer-events

What I've done is have an image layer over a flash that uses my webcam to take a snapshot. I positioned the image correctly over the flash with position: absolute. And added wmode: transparent to my flash embedding. 
Then I need my mouse clicks to be forwarded to my flash content, so my users can allow their webcams to be used. I added point-events: none; to my overlaying image.

The situation here is that everything's displaying correctly cross-browsers, but only on chrome (Windows and Mac) I'm able to click on the "allow" button and actually be able to use my webcam. On Safari, Firefox, IE, they are not letting me click on allow.

I'm wondering if there are known issues with point-events for accessing an underlying flash item, or I'm just having problems with my flash player. Since if I switch my flash to a clickable button underneath my overlaying image, it works perfectly fine.

Comment: Use WebRTC, Flash will soon be dead on desktop and already is for mobile. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WebRTC_API/Taking_still_photos

Comment: Yes, I'm looking to replace all things Flash if I could, just not switching out this plugin yet. And WebRTC isn't supported by Safari or IE right now?